# Rails 4 config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif application-print.css) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 4.0.0-rc2, the line below is causing an error "+" (something about truth) in either production.rb or application.rb. This link refers to it needing to be in application.rb. I am unable to figure out what is causing this error.

https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/pull/36

```
config.assets.precompile=true
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif application-print.css)
```

error in console from capistrano deploy

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
rake aborted!
undefined method `+' for true:TrueClass
```

Comment: How about posting that exact error / stacktrace? And what's the question?

Comment: I have edited the question to show the error. I don't know how to get the trace.

Comment: You're adding a string to a boolean. Don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with the first definition of `config.assets.precompile`.

Try removing the line: `config.assets.precompile=true`, you don't need that.